# What is the standard way to call a method on an array of instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am trying to figure out what the best way is to write a method for an array of instance of a class in ruby on rails.

I have the following solution:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :owned_by, -> (user) { where(:user_id => user.id) }

  def self.get_tokens(user)
    all.owned_by(user).pluck(:tokens)
  end
end
```

I am not totally satisfied with the solutions since the method is called on the class

```
Asset.get_tokens(user)
```

I would rather call it on an array of asset instances without having to do a map in the controller. Something like this:

```
user_assets.get_tokens()
```

Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't need class method, you can call scope directly,

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :owned_by, -> (user) { where(:user_id => user.id) }

end
```

to use, just say `Asset.owned_by(user)`

To get the records in inverse form(from user), assuming, `User` *has_many* `Asset`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def tokens
    assets.pluck(:tokens)
  end

end
```

Which can be called as, `User.find(1).tokens`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an array of items from an array, instead of doing this...

```
array = []
some_collection.each do |item|
  array << item.value
end
```

you can just do this:

```
array = some_collection.map(&:value) # same as some_collection.map { |item| item.value }
```

which is the same as

```
array = some_collection.pluck(:value)
```

Comment: Thanks this is similar to the solution I ended up going for. However, assuming the array treatment is more complex than a simple map or pluck function where would you write this function ? I personally don't like writing these functions in the controller but I don't really see how to implement it in the model.

Comment: Best practice would indicate putting it in your model is better than putting it in your controller. The reason being is that if you need to access the function (we call them methods in ruby) somewhere else in your code, you don't want to have to rewrite code. If your user has many tokens (via assets), adding the method to the User class would be just fine :)

Comment: pluck and map not the same! `pluck` should be much more db communication efficient. While `map` is universal when dealing with arrays and hashes. Still +1 for listing the options.